# Vue.js component render и axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

К примеру есть компонент

```
Vue.component('News', {
        props: {
            data: {
                type: Object,
                default: function() {
                    return {
                        items: []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log('created');

            return axios.get('/news/items')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('data fetched');
                    this.data = response.data.News;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    return Promise.reject(error.status);
                });
        },
        render: function(createElement) {
            console.log('render');
            console.log(this.data.items);
        }
    });
```

Выполнив данный код получим:

```
created
render
undefined //console.log(this.data.items);
data fetched
render
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: io] //console.log(this.data.items);
```

Рендер отработал дважды, первый раз не дожидаясь данные от ajax запроса. Так собственно как заставить отработать его только после получения этих самых данных ? Т.е. чтобы стало так:

```
created
data fetched
render
```

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. это компонент лучше все данные передовать в нутри компонента в

> props:{}

а не

> data(){}

created(),mounted() и другие - будут вызывать все методы, которые завязаны на "цикле жизни" экземпляра -> компонента при его изменении, монитровании и т.д, и описанные в его "теле".

потому, лучше используйте

> computed: {}

Пример:

```
Vue.component('News', {
data() {
    return {
        items: []
    }
},
computed: {
    getNews(){
        return axios.get('/news/items')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.data.News.items;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                return Promise.reject(error.status);
            });   
    }
},
render: function(createElement) {
    console.log('render');
}
```

});

И в нутри тела нужного тега делаем манипуляцию

> `<div v-for="(item, index) in getNews"> {{ item }}</div>`

Comment: Спасибо. Идея понятна. Только шаблон я создаю с помощью createElement(). Получается мне нужно дергать функцию getNews в самом render() ?

Comment: Поправил вопрос на основании вашего ответа. Все равно render отрабатыввает раньше, чем сервер возвращает данные. Поэтому render два раза отрабатывает. Не пойму как присвоить данные в результате ajax запроса до того как render запускается...

Answer (score 1):

В консоли такой порядок действий, поскольку компонент отрисовывается раньше чем разрешается асинхронный запрос данных. В первый раз до прихода данных происходит рендер потому что запрос асинхронный, следовательно код не ждет и выполняется дальше. После того как промис разрешился вы изменяете реактивные данные и компонент рендерится еще раз. Если вы хотите получить данные при загрузке компонента лучше использовать mounted хук, оставив какой-нибудь прелоадер, если хотите отобразить компонент сразу с данными, то лучше отдать их в компонент синхронно через пропсы компонента.